# Asking password verification each time after pushing a href php

Tags: php, passwords, admin

I'm new to php and I wanted to make an admin panel for my website with password verification

Logging in is working well, but each time after pushing a href or anything that makes isset,
it's again asking to verify the password

Here is my code on the page where you'll be logged in:

```
        if ($_POST['username']!='username'&&$_POST['password']!='password') {
            header("location:admin.php?error="); // admin.php is the page where you sign in
        }
        else {
            <HTML></HTML> <!-- here is page of admin after you sign in -->
        }
```

Thanks =)

Comment: It's unclear...you seem to have shown the login code, but where is the code where you check whether the user is already logged in? A proper login system stores the login status in the session, so it doesn't have to keep asking for the password. Did you study any examples of authentication systems written in PHP before attempting this? TBH authentication is not really a topic for beginner, there are so many ways to get it badly wrong, without even realising. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, consider using a ready-made package, and focusing on adding something more interesting to your website.

Comment: This is not real but for the experiment to use new functions that I'm currently learning I wanted to do this on my own and also if there is any way to do it without ```SESSION();``` Anyway thanks.

Comment: No you can't do it without Session. Web applications are stateless by default - no data is persisted across different requests unless you specifically save it somewhere. Session is a type of convenient temporary storage which allows a value to be saved in memory, and therefore be available across multiple requests for a particular user, for the duration of their browser session. That makes it ideal for storing a login status. If you don't want to use Session then the user must send their credentials again with every request.

Comment: APIs, if you're familiar with any, tend to tread a middle road where you present your credentials initially and are then issued with an access token which is valid for a period of time. Every subsequent request must then have that access token in it (until it expires and you must request a new one). This is actually very similar to the session ID (from a cookie) which a browser will send to identify itself to the server - the cookie value ties the browser to the server-side session, which then contains the logged in user ID (if any), so that the application knows the login status every time.